# Is reading from client socket possible after client disconnects?

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, server

I'm trying to write a server program for C that will be able to handle a badly written client program. The client sends a bunch of commands to the server and then closes the socket. After the server executes each command its supposed to send either a 0 or a 1 to the client depending on if the command failed or not.

If I don't try to send the client that one byte after each command, everything is fine and I can continue reading commands server-side, after the client closed the socket. However, if I do try writing that 1 byte, after reading 1 command from the client, I can't read anymore commands(connection reset by peer).

Is there a way to handle this? As in, to be able to write and read all the commands?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The client receives a response from the server, then disconnects. How is the server supposed to get more commands from the client after the client disconnects?

Comment: I was unclear. The client sends x commands to the server, in less time than it takes the server to deal with 1 command (commands are dealt with 1 at a time). If I dont try to write to the client, even after the client closes the socket I can still read the x-1 remaining commands. If I do write to the client, I can't read any more commands.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to know if client awaits your answer to each command before sending another one.
In a typical client-server connection, client starts the communication. Since your client is sending a bunch of commands, there are 2 possibilities:

- In the end of operation your socket return will be OK or NOK.
- For each message the client sends your return will be OK or NOK.

In addition, I suggest you send any trace information, so we can evaluate which solution would better fit in your case.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the socket is OK or NOK?

Comment: If you're connected to your peer, then the socket is ok.
Im afraid I didnt get it exacly..
A socket is an application layer connection, if the host keep listening on the specific port, then the client will be able to send indefinetly

Comment: Is there a way to know if the client disconnects before I try to write? I have a feeling that me trying to write and failling causes issues.

Comment: Yeah it does. If you want to check a socket connection before write, try ( linux like):

>  if ( Socket < 0 )
>    return -1;
> send(...